# moving questions on single page in android

Tags: android

How can I move a question on single page on Android for quiz app using `sqllite` ?

I have used this code for the *next* button:

```
Cursor cus = db.rawQuery("select * from java", null);
cus.moveToNext();

que = cus.getString(0);
question.setText(que);
A = cus.getString(1);
a.setText(A);
B = cus.getString(2);
b.setText(B);
C = cus.getString(3);
c.setText(C);
D = cus.getString(4);
d.setText(D);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: are you getting value properly from db??

Comment: if yes then first get all values from db and put it in arraylist and then iterate through that arraylist and update your ui accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a new question on the click of next button then do someththing like this-

```
      final Cursor cus = db.rawQuery("select * from java", null);
      cus.moveToPosition(-1);
      nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              if (cus.moveToNext()) {
                  que = cus.getString(0);
                  question.setText(que);
                  A = cus.getString(1);
                  a.setText(A);
                  B = cus.getString(2);
                  b.setText(B);
                  C = cus.getString(3);
                  c.setText(C);
                  D = cus.getString(4);
                  d.setText(D);
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "No questions left",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor when the Activity finishes.